# RFC 8767 7. stale data vs new lookup

Tags: domain-name-system

The [section 7 of the RFC 8767](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8767#section-7) says:

> Because modern resolvers use techniques like prefetching and
> request coalescing for    efficiency, it is not necessary that every
> client request needs to    trigger a new lookup flow in the presence
> of stale data, but rather    that a good-faith effort has been
> recently made to refresh the stale    data before it is delivered to
> any client.

I do not get the limit of this recommendation.
Let's say I have "abc.com" in my cache that had a TTL of 1 hour and expired for 30 mins already, and have "xyz.com" that had a TTL of 1 hour and expired for 20 mins already.
If I keep the stale data for 12 hours, should I serve first the stale data (because it has expired not long time ago) or should I try to refresh first?

In the document, it says stale data can be served if the client timer is expired (~1.8s) but suggest now to return first stale data in some cases. But I do not understand what are those cases.

> but rather    that a good-faith effort has been recently made to
> refresh the stale    data

Does it mean I can server stale data immediately if the resolver tried to refresh the data at least once before the TTL expire? whatever the request could be successfully refreshed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you are quoting is in the context of this (immediately before your text):

> Stale data is used only when refreshing has failed in order to adhere
> to the original intent of the design of the DNS and the behavior
> expected by operators.  If stale data were to always be used
> immediately and then a cache refresh attempted after the client
> response has been sent, the resolver would frequently be sending data
> that it would have had no trouble refreshing.

What it means is that only when the resolver does not manage to fetch new data before the "client response timer" fires (which is where the suggested 1.8s is relevant, earlier in the text), it is allowed to serve stale data (with shortened TTL).

This also does not mean that it stops processing this lookup just because it served stale data to the client. It should still try to finish the lookup and update the cache for the future to try to avoid serving stale data the next time.

If the lookup is not just slower than "client response timer" (suggested 1.8s) but rather that it is slower than the "query resolution timer" (max time for a query, suggested 10-30s) or even outright impossible, then it is suggested that it only needs to attempt the query again every "failure recheck timer" seconds (suggested 30s).

Ie, if you tried to refresh within the last 30s (or whatever failure recheck timer is used) and that attempt outright failed (or possibly is still ongoing), you are good to serve stale data. Otherwise no.

You should see it as the goal to *not* serve stale data. What RFC8767 says is essentially that when the traditional behavior would have been to time out (from the client's point of view) or to return an error because you can't get current data, you are allowed to temporarily serve stale data while you are continuing to try to get the current data.

From [Section 5.  Example Method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8767#section-5):

> When a recursive resolver receives a request, it should start the
> client response timer.  This timer is used to avoid client timeouts.
> It should be configurable, with a recommended value of 1.8 seconds as
> being just under a common timeout value of 2 seconds while still
> giving the resolver a fair shot at resolving the name.
>
> The resolver then checks its cache for any unexpired records that
> satisfy the request and returns them if available.  If it finds no
> relevant unexpired data and the Recursion Desired flag is not set in
> the request, it should immediately return the response without
> consulting the cache for expired records.  Typically, this response
> would be a referral to authoritative nameservers covering the zone,
> but the specifics are implementation dependent.
>
> If iterative lookups will be done, then the failure recheck timer
> is    consulted.  Attempts to refresh from non-responsive or otherwise
> failing authoritative nameservers are recommended to be done no more
> frequently than every 30 seconds.  If this request was received
> within this period, the cache may be immediately consulted for stale
> data to satisfy the request.
>
> Outside the period of the failure recheck timer, the resolver
> should    start the query resolution timer and begin the iterative
> resolution    process.  This timer bounds the work done by the
> resolver when    contacting external authorities and is commonly
> around 10 to 30    seconds.  If this timer expires on an attempted
> lookup that is still    being processed, the resolution effort is
> abandoned.
>
> If the answer has not been completely determined by the time the
> client response timer has elapsed, the resolver should then check its
> cache to see whether there is expired data that would satisfy the
> request.  If so, it adds that data to the response message with a TTL
> greater than 0 (as specified in Section 4).  The response is then
> sent to the client while the resolver continues its attempt to
> refresh the data.
>
> When no authorities are able to be reached during a resolution
> attempt, the resolver should attempt to refresh the delegation and
> restart the iterative lookup process with the remaining time on the
> query resolution timer.  This resumption should be done only once per
> resolution effort.
>
> Outside the resolution process, the maximum stale timer is used for
> cache management and is independent of the query resolution process.
> This timer is conceptually different from the maximum cache TTL that
> exists in many resolvers, the latter being a clamp on the value of
> TTLs as received from authoritative servers and recommended to be    7
> days in the TTL definition in Section 4.  The maximum stale timer
> should be configurable.  It defines the length of time after a record
> expires that it should be retained in the cache.  The suggested value
> is between 1 and 3 days.

Comment: This is now very clear! Thank you